# ImportError: No module named 'matplotlib' porque hay dos Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Utilisando Python 3, en un jupyter notebook intento importar matplotlib

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use("ggplot")
%matplotlib inline
```

Pero el me contesta :

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-53aa8d9f8ebb> in <module>()
      3 import pandas as pd
      4 import numpy as np
----> 5 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      6 plt.style.use("ggplot")
      7 get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')

ImportError: No module named 'matplotlib'
```

Creo que tengo dos Pythons instalados en su máquina, uno es el python estándar que viene con Linux y el segundo es el que instalé con los puertos (este es el que tiene matplotlib instalado en su biblioteca, el que viene con Linux lo hace no).

Pueden ayudarme arreglar este problema ?

### Actualización 6/01/2018

Cuando utiliso lo siguiente :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use("ggplot")
%matplotlib inline
```

Me da lo mismo

Comment: @PatricioMoracho No, definitivamente.

Comment: Ya volví atrás el voto, el problema es tener varias pestaña abiertas

Comment: @PatricioMoracho Entendido ;)

Comment: Si instalaste dependencias para python3 y el python por defecto en tu máquina es el 2.7, entonces tu archivo debiera empezar con `#!/usr/bin/env python3`.

Comment: @amenadiel Él sigue enviándome este error

Comment: Tal vez tengas que hacerte un virtualenv e instalar las dependencias dentro de éste

Comment: @amenadiel Si, tiene un buen tutorial para hacerlo ? Y para hacerlo dentro de Jupyter Notebook ?

Comment: Encontré este: https://medium.com/@rohitsinha/jupyter-notebook-in-projects-virtual-env-df7cd686bd94 lo importante es usar explícitamente python3 para crear el virtualenv y luego pip3 para instalar los paquetes una vez que actives el virtualenv